# after install just_audio package in flutter received error "Execution failed for task ':audio_session:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'."

Tags: flutter, build.gradle, just-audio

I received this error after installing the just_audio package in Flutter. I searched hard to solve my problem but did not find the answer.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audio_session:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':audio_session:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find media2-session-1.1.3.jar (androidx.media2:media2-session:1.1.3).
     Searched in the following locations:
        https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/media2/media2-session/1.1.3/media2-session-1.1.3.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I installed these packages in pubspec.yaml

```
 just_audio: ^0.9.18
 audio_service: ^0.18.1
 audio_session: ^0.1.6+1
 just_audio_platform_interface: ^4.0.0
```